# How to use google font for Blazor on Index.razor page

Tags: c#, css, blazor

```
@page "/"

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans');
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Work Sans';
        color: #4d4d4d;
    }
        
</style>
```

In React.js I can simply use the @import to use tag to use Google Font, but in Blazor I got the error `The name 'import' does not exist in current context`. What is the correct way of using Google Font globally for a Blazor app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@` is used to prefix Razor code, so you need to escape it with a second `@`. Try:

```html
 . . .
<style>
@@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans');
 . . .
```

Alternatively, if you want this localized to a single page, use [CSS-Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

- Create an *Index.razor.css* file in the same directory as *Index.razor*.
- This is a "normal" css file, so you can write css as you would normally without worrying about escaping `@`.

Comment: @@ import statements do not work in localised CSS files. The first option is the only one that currently works with blazor.

Comment: @NeilMeyer, I think you misunderstand: .razor.css files are just css so you use regular `@import` syntax (without the second `@`).

Answer (score 3):

In blazor, adding font's is a little bit more complex than reactjs.

## Steps

1. Add a new directory called fonts to wwwroot
2. Download .woff font file
3. Copy .woff file to the fonts directory in wwwroot
4. Then in site.css apply the following CSS

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: '<FONT-FAMILY>';
    src: url('../fonts/<FONT.WOFF>');
}
```

replace `FONT.WOFF` with  the name of your font and `FONT-FAMILY` with the name of the font family you're using! I got this from [this blog](https://www.kevinwilliams.dev/adding-a-custom-font-to-blazor/)

Comment: Does ttf not work?

Comment: The linked blog post not longer exists (there).